# Positioning with GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I've a positioning problem with the GridBagLayout : 
I try to place in center (at the top) a label but with my code (for a reason which I didn't see), I've this : 
[image]

I want that the label Test are at the top of my window and in center. Someone can explain me the reason of this bad positionnement ?

My program :

```
public class Accueil extends JFrame {

    private JPanel home = new JPanel();
    private GridBagConstraints grille = new GridBagConstraints();
    private JLabel title = new JLabel("Test");

    public Accueil() {
        home.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        init_grille();
        init_title();

        this.add(home);
        this.setSize(600,600);
        this.setTitle("Test One");
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    private void init_grille() { 
        grille.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        grille.weightx = 2;
        grille.weighty = 5;
        grille.ipady=grille.anchor=GridBagConstraints.CENTER;;

    }

    private void init_title() {
        grille.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        grille.gridx = 0;
        grille.gridy = 0;
        home.add(title,grille);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        new Accueil();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not using GridBagLayout, but GridLayout.

Comment: if you intented to use GridLayout, you need to change your tags

Answer (score 1):

This won't help:

```
home.setLayout(new GridLayout());
```

You probably want:

```
home.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
```

Also, these changes should work:

```
private void init_title() {
      grille.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
      grille.gridx = 0;
      grille.gridy = 0;
      grille.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
      home.add(title,grille);
  }
```

Comment: Between the GridBagLayout and GridLayout, which is the "best" ? I  mean "best" in the sense of placement of differents compenents

Comment: There is no best. When you need a simple grid, GridLayout fits best and is easier to use. When you need something more complex, GridLayout can't do, and GridBagLayout can, but at the price of a higher complexity.

Comment: +1 to JB. Since we don't know your final objective of what components you have or where you want them placed, suggesting a preferred LayoutManager is just guessing.

Comment: +1 but (I'm against to complicating the simple things) OPs `I try to place in center (at the top) a label but` talking about SwingConstants.CENTER or JLabel.CENTER instead of bothering with LayoutManager in this case, nor if is XxxLayout better than another

Comment: Thank you everybody for your answers. It's help me a lot :)

Comment: You could use GridLayout and by use setHoriztonalPoaition and setVerticalPosition on the JLabel, get it to appear in the middle. GridBagLayout is more flexible, but also more complex and the choice will come down what it is you want to achieve